# Yii2 в foreach много dropDownList

Tags: yii2

Всем привет, что я не так делаю

```
<?php 
$form = ActiveForm::begin(); 
foreach ($regionCity as $region): 
$arrayRegion = [$region['id'] => $region['name_ru']];
echo $form->field($model, 'region')->dropDownList($arrayRegion);
endforeach;
echo'<br><br>' . Html::submitButton('Сохранить', ['class' => 'btn 
btn-success']);
$form = ActiveForm::end(); 
?>
```

http://joxi.ru/MAjBWNZHe9qNAe.png

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [ArrayHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#map()-detail) и с помощь его собрать массив значений:

```
<?php 
$form = ActiveForm::begin(); 
echo $form->field($model, 'region')->dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($regionCity, 'id', 'name_ru'));
echo'<br><br>' . Html::submitButton('Сохранить', ['class' => 'btn 
btn-success']);
$form = ActiveForm::end(); 
?>
```

Comment: она ругается на Calling unknown method: yii\widgets\ActiveForm::label()

Comment: @Uman отредактировал ответ

Comment: нечего не меняется, все остается по прежнему как на картинки

Comment: Как должно быть правильно тогда?

Comment: должен быть выпадающий список с областями

Comment: @Uman отредактировал ответ

Comment: спасибо получилось, еще такой вопрос если можно, у меня в таблицы запихнуты области и города (id, parent_id, name_ru), получается если я буду делать с помощью ArrayHelper::map, то не получится